# Json to C# object with google spreadsheet

Tags: c#, json.net, google-sheets

**EDITED**:

If I load a google spreadsheet using JSON URL into a dynamic C# object, I can't access some entries because the JSON looks like this:

```
"author": [
  {
    "name": {
      "$t": "XYZ"
    },
    "email": {
      "$t": "XYZ@gmail.com"
    }
  }
]
```

Why does the google JSON have $ namespaces? Can we remove them? What can be done?

Here is the code:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"GoogleUrlWithJson");
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string a = jsonObj.feed.entry[0].author.name.$t; ==> Can't compile error "unexpected $"
```

Comment: perhaps the converter can not convert the `$` which is probably part of some code that tries to convert the .XLS file why not use some of .NETS JSON assemblies that can do that type of work for you.. I think there are some .net Deserilizers and Serializers out there on SO

Comment: Actually I think that Ill use the Google Spreadsheet API instead of using directly the JSON file, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using square bracket syntax to access the JSON property names that have `$` in them:

```
string a = jsonObj.feed.entry[0].author.name["$t"];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, now what if my node "name" was actually called "name$menu" and that everything else remained the same? 

    ex: string a = jsonObj.feed.entry[0].author.name$menu["$t"]; ?? what do we do for this one?

Comment: Same thing.  `string a = jsonObj.feed.entry[0].author["name$menu"]["$t"];`